# how to detect if app use not system IME keyboard in swift

Tags: swift

In my country user use other IME keyboard, and i want to know whether app use system keyboard.

I try to use `UITextInputMode.activeInputModes()`, but this method has a bug. See [UITextInputMode.activeInputModes() crashes in Swift 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32691424/uitextinputmode-activeinputmodes-crashes-in-swift-2/)

Comment: Using the workaround to get the active input modes, could you share the results with the various keyboards you want to test?

Comment: @Molanda Thanks for comment. I try to get keyboard with `UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window!!.textInputMode`. Come from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22614489/uitextinputmode-currentinputmode-is-deprecated-suggested-replacement)